# What is the maximum length of a Salesforce users password in characters?

Tags: user, passwords

What is the maximum number of characters that a Salesforce user password can have?

According to [Setting Password Policies](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=admin_password.htm&siteLang=en_US):

> User passwords cannot exceed 16,000 bytes.

How does that translate into characters that the user would enter in the browser for their password?

---

Firstly, what character encoding is Salesforce using?

This I think I can answer:

> ## [Internationalization and Character Sets](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm#topic-title_international)
>
> [...] The character set for your organization depends on the Salesforce instance your organization uses. If your organization logs into `ssl.salesforce.com`, then your encoding is `ISO-8859-1`. All other instances use `UTF-8`. You can determine the character set for your organization by calling `describeGlobal()` and inspecting the encoding value returned in the [DescribeGlobalResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal_describeglobalresult.htm#topic-title).

## UTF-8

With UTF-8 it looks like the a character could be 1, 2 or 4 bytes (Ref: [What is the maximum number of bytes for a UTF-8 encoded character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533258/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-bytes-for-a-utf-8-encoded-character)). So, I think, if all the characters were in the [U+0000 to U+007F code point range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) then I could get up to 16,000 characters in a password.

---

In the ideal world this would never be an issue with API integrations and I'd use an OAuth refresh token to maintain a session from an external system.

This question came about with an older system that had a maximum password length of 36 characters. I'm looking at increasing it, but getting a defined maximum password length isn't as straight forward as you might think. Ideally I won't be replacing one arbitrary upper limit with another one.

I personally haven't encountered any 8000+ character passwords. They are hard to remember and difficult to type out. But the potential exists.

Comment: perfect. You can use this tool to calculate UTF-8 string length & byte counter. http://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any character can be a 1 'code-point' or a combination of two 'code-points' (e.g. á can be described as two code points (a+') in one character) and every code-point can be 1 to 6 bytes (or 4, since the 2003 spec).

So theoretically one character could use up to 12 bytes.

Now I don't think that will happen, and in the new spec 8 bytes would be the max, but if you want to be safe I would divide that 16,000 by 12. Now that still gives plenty possible password for a user to choose from, I would say :-)

Oh, and this is a great read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: So the answer is: 1333.33333333 ?